# Swift why does my NSTimer not fire evenly?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a function called `changeBallColor()`that is called every time a NSTimer I made fires (which is set to 2 second intervals). The goal is to change the ball color every 2 seconds to a random color without repeating two colors in a row. Except the color changes almost instantly sometimes and other times take 4 seconds to change. When it takes longer to change, I noticed in the xcode debugger that the CPU usage spikes to 99% momentarily before the color changes. Does `arc4random_uniform()` take a while to complete or something (in the instances where the while loop is used)? If so, how can I optimize this code so it runs flawlessly? Sorry I'm a noob when it comes to Swift.

```
func changeBallColor() {
    var previousint: UInt32?
    var randint = arc4random_uniform(4)
    while previousint == randint {
        randint = arc4random_uniform(4)
    }
    previousint = randint

    if previousint == 0 {
        imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_g.png")
    } else if previousint == 1 {
        imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_b.png")
    } else if previousint == 2 {
        imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_r.png")
    } else if previousint == 3 {
        imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_y.png")
    }  
}
```

Comment: your logic for not hitting the same color twice is faulty since `previousint` is a local variable. Consider adding `print` statements telling you what random numbers get hit in the loop and how often the loop gets executed (always 0 times) etc.

Comment: Oh duh... `previousint` is getting redeclared every time the NSTimer fires which is messing it up. Moved it up to the top of my ViewController class and it runs flawlessly now. Thanks and sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no explanation for the CPU spike but the 4 seconds are easily explained by the fact that your code to prevent getting the same number twice in a row is faulty. Every time you enter the `changeBallColor` a new `previousint` is created with `nil` as its default value.

That causes the loop to not be executed at all since `nil` is never equal to anything `arc4random_uniform(4)` returns.

## Solution

Move the definition of `previousint` out of method into your class to make it keep its value across consecutive calls of `changeBallColor`:

```
class ABC {
    var previousint: UInt32?

    func changeBallColor() {
        var randint = arc4random_uniform(4)
        while previousint == randint {
            print("loop")
            randint = arc4random_uniform(4)
        }
        previousint = randint
        
        if previousint == 0 {
            imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_g.png")
        } else if previousint == 1 {
            imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_b.png")
        } else if previousint == 2 {
            imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_r.png")
        } else if previousint == 3 {
            imageBall.image = UIImage(named: "circle_y.png")
        }  
    }
}
```